# Replacement-List Macro Function [Question]

Tags: c++, module, macros

#### Replacement-List Macro Function

---

I'm attempting to create a quick macro which will allow me to simply get a class pointer and name the setup module based from the class pointer name like so:

```
#define dll_import(...) dll_module->__VA_ARGS__= \
GetModuleHandleW(L#__VA_ARGS__.dll)  // Note: This is where I'm confused.
```

When I attempt this It obviously wont work because I can't just tack on *".dll"* to the argument, as it's outside the string's argument inclusion:

[image] Just a visual example from my reference to help. Ignore the expression catch error.

Currently I'm just curious to see if anyone knows a way around this, all help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if this is just a matter of concatenating strings you should be able to do `GetModuleHandleW(L#__VA_ARGS__ L".dll")`. This would produce a string like `L"verified_module" L".dll"` which the language will concatenate into a single string literal

Comment: @Human-Compiler Yeah, that seemed to work fine, thanks!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer in that case

Comment: really sorry, but it is a bit funny that you put [Question] on your title, but missed to put an actual question in your question.

Comment: if you really do use macros you should find out what flag you need to pass to your compiler to see the output of preprocessing only. This is essential to debug macro expansion. For gcc it is -E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to simply concatenate strings together. If that's the case, the solution should just be to make sure that the `.dll` portion is a string literal as well:

```cpp
#define dll_import(...) dll_module->__VA_ARGS__= \
    GetModuleHandleW(L#__VA_ARGS__ L".dll")
```

This would convert an input of `dll_import(verified_module)` into:

```cpp
dll_module->verified_module = GetModuleHandleW(L"verified_module" L".dll")
```

Which C++ will see as two subsequent string literals and concatenate together as one, `L"verified_module.dll"`